# Java PreparedStatement Cross-DB with casting

Tags: java, mysql, database, oracle, prepared-statement

I have a PreparedStatement intended to be run both on ORACLE and on MYSQL.
But I cannot figure out how to handle the CAST(NULL AS ...)

On Oracle the following works (but not on Mysql):

```
SELECT TIMB_INS,
CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP) AS TIMB_CLO
FROM TOPS
```

On Mysql the following works (but not on Oracle):

```
SELECT TIMB_INS,
CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) AS TIMB_CLO
FROM TOPS
```

(Please note that the first column selected, "TIMB_INS", returns the correct data type for target database type in both cases, i.e. TIMESTAMP for Oracle and DATETIME for MySql.)

There is a way to put it so that it works for both?
I.E. Can i make it db-indipendent in some way?

Thanks
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the tags I can see you're calling this statement from some java code. There are several ways doing so:

- Use the [DAO](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm) pattern. I.e. for each SQL flavor provide a java file that contains the SQL-s.
- Use an ORM like [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) or [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html). That will take care of this kind of differences.
- As a quick hack, you can edit the SQL manually, like in the snippet below. But then you have to determine somehow if the underlying database is Oracle or MySQL

  String SQL_PATTERN = "... CAST(NULL AS %s) AS TIMB_CLO ...";

  String SQL = String.format(SQL_PATTERN, isOracle ? "TIMESTAMP" : "DATETIME");

Comment: Yes it's a call from a standalone java application.
I think your third solution may do the trick, althought I would have liked to solve it (brilliantly?) from sql only. But maybe it's simply not possible.
(Thank you of your quick reply!)

Comment: Maybe there's an SQL solution too. I just don't have the tools to experiment with those for you.

Comment: Another - not so brilliant - solution would be adding in that table, on both DBs, a NOT USED (null) column of the desired type and selecting it.
However for simplicity sake we went for your third solution. We peeked db name from "connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName()".
Thanks! ;-) Bye.

Comment: NB i would give +1 to your solution but still i cannot since as a newbie i'm low in reputation

Comment: You can still accept it with the tick below the up and down arrows :)